# Automatically delete old trace Zipkin entries in Cassandra

Tags: kubernetes, cassandra-3.0, zipkin

Our Cassandra PVC keeps getting full no matter how much we increase its size by. We need old Zipkin data to be automatically deleted to solve this issue.

I've read their docs and know that trace data and indexes have default TTLs of 7 days and 3 days respectively - https://github.com/openzipkin/zipkin/tree/master/zipkin-storage/cassandra#time-to_live.

But the default TTLs don't seem to work for our environment. Is there a way to edit the default TTLs? I tried setting the CASSANDRA_SPAN_TTL and CASSANDRA_INDEX_TTL environment variables but they had no effect. I also tried following these directions - [https://github.com/openzipkin/zipkin/tree/master/zipkin-server#:~:text=We%20use%20yaml,overridden%20that%20way](https://github.com/openzipkin/zipkin/tree/master/zipkin-server#:%7E:text=We%20use%20yaml,overridden%20that%20way). - to mount a zipkin-server.properties file but I get this error when deploying Zipkin:

```
Error: Could not find or load main class org.springframework.boot.loader.PropertiesLauncher
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.boot.loader.PropertiesLauncher
```

Any assistance would be appreciated.